# Sub-projects not building in Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode4

I've got a bunch of projects which build on their own, creating static libraries, that I've dropped into another project.  I've added the static libraries created by these sub-projects to the "Link Binary With Libraries" and "Target Dependencies" build phases for the main project.

When I build the main project, absolutely nothing happens with the sub-projects.  They don't get built, and, even crazier, the main project reports no link errors even though it has five required libraries that don't exist.

I've googled and read several blog posts about setting this up, and it seems like I've done everything correctly. But clearly not, unless this is an Xcode bug (I've seen plenty of people saying this has been unstable in Xcode 4).

Can anyone suggest steps I may have missed, or anything else that might make this work?

Comment: It turns out that the sub-projects actually were being built, even though the product of each project was still red (i.e. missing).

I'm leaving the question here in case this bites someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the targets for these subprojects to the build scheme?  Edit the scheme and make sure you add a target for each one of the subprojects.  Theoretically you shouldn't have to add target dependencies, as Xcode should figure out the dependencies between all the targets in a scheme.

Comment: Even though it turns out there was no problem, I'll accept your answer anyway because that is one of the things we had to check.  Xcode had done it correctly, but very few of the resources that talk about adding sub-projects mention this.